# launch a php script at the end of a bash script

Tags: php, bash, cron

I'm setting up a daily routine via a bash script sitting in cron.daily, launched by a cronjob.

1. db dump into vhost folder
2. zip vhost folder
3. rotate vhost folder in backup rotation folders
4. launch custom php script

All is fine except the very last step. I'm not sure how to write it down, so it might just be the syntax? Or it may be that the process exits after the bash backup.sh call ? I'm not sure how i can "chain" scripts in bash.

Here is the end of the bash script.

```
# 3. Run backup rotate

cd $BACKUP_DIR
bash backup.sh

# 4. run SAP Export
/usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhost/domain.com/export.cron.php
```

Comment: did you have errors? can you run it in bash not bash script? is the php use relative paths? is the php written to run in apache env, if so some distro use different php.ini for php cli, so some variable defined in apache php.ini is not found in cli php.ini.

Comment: I can run it via command line. No errors reported. My question is more whether the syntax in my bash script is correct and if it is okay to first launch backup.sh and then the export script. Will they be run in parallel or consecutively ?

Comment: do ./backup.sh then they run in sequence. it you need 100% certainty. do touch backup.lock before backup.sh then remove it when complete. php script check for lock file.

Comment: so If i understand you correctly, I should remove the `bash backup.sh`line and write instead './backup.sh' ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check file execution permissions for **/var/www/vhost/domain.com/export.cron.php** 
you can't run the php script with out file execution permissions.

Try below commands (give full permissions) 
$ **chmod 777 /var/www/vhost/domain.com/export.cron.php** 
$ **/usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhost/domain.com/export.cron.php**